# Order type of the set of all the limit elements in $\omega^{\omega}$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

What do you think is the order type of $\{\alpha\in\omega^{\omega}:\alpha\ \text{is a limit ordinal number}\}$?

My first thought was $\omega$, but when I visualize the above mentioned set, $\omega^2$ seems to have countably many limit elements, let alone $\omega^{\omega}$. So the other guess is $\omega^{\omega}$, but it's not possible. I'm clueless now...

Any hints?

Comment: Why do you claim that $\omega^\omega$ not possible?

Comment: Oh, I just thought a subset of a set cannot have the same ordinal number as the set itself, but it seems I'm wrong.

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal in the first line?

Comment: oh man, yeah, I did

Comment: You are almost done with your realization regarding $\omega^2$. Answer the same question for $\omega^3,\omega^4$, etc, and that will give you the result.

Comment: I see. The answer is still $\omega^\omega$. I will write an answer.

Comment: @Jules For an easier example where a subset of a set has the same ordinal number as the set itself, consider $\{2,3,4,5,6, \cdots\}$ which has order type $\omega$ and is a subset of $\omega=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6, \cdots\}$

Comment: Yup, I realized that :)

Comment: Also another example of an ordinal that the limit ordinals below it have the same order type: $\omega_1$, or any uncountable cardinal for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is actually $\omega^\omega$.

You can find a bijection form $\{\alpha\in\omega^{\omega}:\alpha\ \text{is a limit ordinal number}\}$ to $\omega^\omega$ by mapping the ordinal $\omega^{n+1}\cdot a_n+\omega^{n}\cdot a_{n-1}+\omega^{n-1}\cdot a_{n-2}\cdots \omega^2\cdot a_1+\omega \cdot a_0$ to $\omega^n\cdot a_n+\omega^{n-1}\cdot a_{n-1}+\omega^{n-2}\cdot a_{n-2}\cdots \omega\cdot a_1+a_0$

Comment: Wait, but how is for instance $\omega$ + 4 a limit ordinal?

Comment: @Jules $\omega^2+\omega\cdot 4$ is mapped to $\omega+4$. I have the wrong direction and will fix it, as well as the bad notation for ordinal arithmetic.